# Angularjs $http.get not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, http-get

on my server side (ASP.ne MVC) I have method which looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetTrenings(string treningId)
    {
        var tempId = Guid.Parse(treningId);
        var trening = TreningService.GetTreningById(tempId);
        _trenings = TreningService.GetAllTreningsForUser(trening.UserId);
        return Json(_trenings, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

And I have Angular service :

```
publicApp.angularModule.factory('feedSingleTreningService', function ($q, $http) {

return {
   getTrenings: function (data) {
       var input = $http.get("/Feed/GetTrenings", { params: { treningId: data } });


        var deferred = $q.defer();

        deferred.resolve(input);
        return deferred.promise;
    },

};
});
```

And In my Controller I call this service like this:

```
 feedSingleTreningService.getTrenings(data).then(function(results) {
        console.log("test", results);
    });
```

But nothing is shown in console, I've debugged server side and request reaches it, and it returns _trenings, also service returns promise, but nothing happens.

I've changed then to finally, and in console "test" was shown but results were undefined.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to defer your call to $http because it already returns a promise.

Just return

```
return $http.get("/Feed/GetTrenings", { params: { treningId: data } });
```

then anything that calls your function can do:

```
getTrenings(myData).then(function(data) { do something }).fail(function() { error });
```

Comment: I've made changes you've suggested but still then isn't "fired"

Comment: did you add a fail() function also to see if you are getting an error?  Also use the network tab in firebug/chrome to see if it's making an HTTP request and what the response looks like.

Comment: It wasn't problem with angular, but with .net, I got error The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.